# Same initial context for multiple wars in tomcat

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, servlets, servlet-mapping

I have 3 separate wars in tomcat and each war contains some restful services, now there are different clients in wars that are calling those services for example
servlet maping in war1 is

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

access URL will `localhost:8080/projectName/services/someservice`

similarly in war2

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Servlet2</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/postprocessorservices/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

access URL will be `localhost:8080/differentProjectName/postprocessorservices/someotherservice`

I simply want to know that is there a way to provide a common initial context so that same initial context is used in different client for example

```
localhost:8080/commoncontext/services/someservice
localhost:8080/commoncontext/postprocessorservices/someotherservice
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could create a facade project that will redirect the calls to the proper services, but i think that it will be an waste of time. Given that you already have clients to those services, just define on then the service it will access.

Comment: You could also use this solution: https://rvdb.wordpress.com/2012/04/26/reverse-proxying-tomcat-webapps-behind-apache/ that is mentioned on this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18438820/460557